# C - Returned array fills the array with the first value only

Tags: c, arrays

My problem is that when I create a local array in the function and return it, all the values in the array become assigned to the array's first value. So for an example, an array of size 4 with the values 3, 5, 11, 13 is returned. The array now only has the values 3, 3, 3, 3. I'm fairly new to coding, so any help would be appreciated.

```
uint8_t* half( const uint8_t array[],
           unsigned int cols,
           unsigned int rows )
{

    int size = (cols / 2) * (rows / 2);

    uint8_t *newarray = malloc( size * sizeof(int) );

    float average;

    for (int i = 0; i < (rows / 2); i++) {

        for (int k = 0; k < (cols / 2); k++) {

            average = (array[ (2*k) + (2*i*cols) ] + array[ ((2*k) + 1) + (2*i*cols) ] + array[ ((2*k) + 1) + ((2*i*cols) + cols) ] + array[ (2*k) + ((2*i*cols) + cols) ]) / 4.0;

            newarray[k + (i * (cols / 2))] = (int)( round(average) );

        }
    }

    return newarray;

}


int main () {

    uint8_t *halfarray;

    halfarray = half(testarray, test_width, test_height);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

        printf("values in array %d\n", *halfarray);

    }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are only printing the first element. `printf("values in array %d\n", *halfarray);` --> `printf("values in array %d\n", halfarray[i]);`

Comment: Oh, that makes sense.

Comment: Ok it works, thanks lol.

Comment: @kaylum Please post that as an answer :)

Comment: Looks like a simple typographic error to me and I have voted as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing this line:

```
printf("values in array %d\n", *halfarray);
```

to this:

```
printf("values in array %d\n", *halfarray);
halfarray++
```

Comment: This is poor, as in order to free the memory, `halfarray` will just have to be decreased again after the loop.

Comment: Did you just plagiarize a comment?

Comment: @AdrianM. Bwa hahaha yes I did!

Comment: @kaylum You might need to reference that comment ;).

Comment: if he made a print_array function, and passed in halfarray, then on return he could free it without decrementing

Answer (score 0):

Use pointer arithmetic at each iteration to increment the position of the non-constant pointer, thusly:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++, halfarray++) {

    printf("values in array %d\n", *halfarray);

}
```

Comment: This is poor, as in order to free the memory, `halfarray` will just have to be decreased again after the loop